# AWS Elastic Beanstalk won't deploy my Rails app even once

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm currently using the "Ruby 2.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.0.2" image, and by looking, inside the EC2 instance at the /var/logs/eb-engine.log ("eb logs" command won't show me this), there is a recurring error:

> [ERROR] failed to parse JSON file
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_version_manifest.json with error:
>   json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field
>   AppVersionManifest.Serial of type uint64

When I check that file, I do not know what is wrong with it, or what is preventing that file from being parsed, if that is actually the problem:

```
{ "RuntimeSources":{"my_api":{"my_api-source_alfa0.2":"s3url":""}}},"DeploymentId":9,"Serial":"23","VersionLabel":"my_api-source_alfa0.2"}
```

The serial "23" seems pretty parsable to me. Please help!

Comment: Have you tried using `23` as a number instead of a string of `"23"`?

Comment: Actually, I did not create that file: AWS EB creates it and would do it again everytime the instance is automatically re-deployed.

Comment: I'm currently watching this very recent thread reporting the same https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=206033

Comment: Maybe you can still change it? That error is saying an integer is expected, but there that number is actually a string in the file.

Comment: @kichik Thanks a lot for your reply. Well, I tried when you suggested it, but my user does not have admin rights to write that file.

Comment: If you look in the logs, you'll see EB is downloading that file from S3 (2020/07/14 22:58:41.937541 [INFO] Downloading: bucket: elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-603873217483, object: /resources/environments/e-k9bptzbdbu/_runtime/versions/manifest_1594766763384) , where the Serial is a string. Change it to an Int there, and it works. Obviously that is not a long term fix, but keep an eye on the aws thread mentioned above because it's definitely an AWS bug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What causes this

I believe this is a bug.

In some cases, this can occur if you try to [terminate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.terminating.html) or [rebuild](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-management-rebuild.html) your Elastic Beanstalk environment and the operation fails to delete your `AWSEBSecurityGroup`.

There are reports (see comments) of other causes besides this.

### How to fix it

The AWS document [*How do I terminate or rebuild my AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment when the `AWSEBSecurityGroup` fails to delete?*](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-deletion-failure/) describes how to resolve this, but I excerpted the main steps below, in case that link ever breaks:

> 1. Open the [AWS CloudFormation console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/).
> 2. From the **Stack Name** column, choose the stack that failed to delete.
>
>    > Note: The **Status** column of your stack shows **DELETE_FAILED**.
> 3. From the **Actions** menu, choose **Delete Stack**.
> 4. In the **Delete Stack** pop-up window, choose **AWSEBSecurityGroup**, and then choose **Yes, Delete**.
> 5. Terminate or rebuild the Elastic Beanstalk environment.

The linked docs have other steps if you prefer the CLI or have a more complex setup.

### Then what?

After you've deleted the group and rebuilt your environment, you won't get the `app_version_manifest.json` error any more. Deploy your app.

Once it's done, if you SSH in and run…

```
cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_version_manifest.json
```

…you'll notice that `Serial` is now correctly represented as a JSON number.

Comment: Do you have any idea what is the reason of the issue? 

In my case, there was no failed security group deletion. I was testing the instance startup procedure and manually terminated EC2 instance and got this issue (Amazon Linux 2/3.0.3, python). This scenario worked for me on the previous platform (Amazon Linux 1) and I am worrying about this happening on production if the instance becomes unavailable. 

In general, this looks like some bug in elastic beanstalk startup scripts - why would the "Serial" field suddenly become string? Why this can not be handled when parsing the json file?

Comment: I can confirm that manually terminated EC2 was not the cause. I had to rebuild the environment (didn't help) and then redeploy and it suddenly started working (the "Serial" field became integer again). After that, I terminated the EC2 manually again and this time the new instance was started by ElasticBeanstalk without a problem.

Comment: Definitely seems like a bug. There might be causes other than the one I identified.

Comment: Also seeing this, not sure how it can be security group related. This is all generated by Elastic Beanstalk. Have reached out to a Solution Architect at AWS...

Comment: I also posted an issue here - https://github.com/aws/elastic-beanstalk-roadmap/issues/75 (didn't find better place), there is also a related discussion here - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=947760#947760

Comment: Thanks @AaronBrager!!! I gave up and was manually running it in a barebones EC2 instance. Today I tested your method and it worked after solving other minor issues.