# Elastic beanstalk fails to deploy Node.js app (works on one environment, but crashes on the other one)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I connected the CodePipeline to ElasticBeanstalk and it worked ok for the last couple of days.
Now after one deploy (only added one console.log in my app) the deploy started failing with the following error:

> failed to parse JSON file
> /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_version_manifest.json with error:
> json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field
> AppVersionManifest.Serial of type uint64

I checked that file and it contains a valid JSON.

Tried to revert the last commit, but still the same issue.
When I deploy the same code to other environment on ElasticBeanstalk, it works normally so the problem is probably not related to the app code.

Tried to increase the instance size, but that didn't help as well.

Any ideas what's causing the problem?

Comment: Do you have a build action in your CP? Maybe it also got changed and messes up the new application version?

Comment: I do. But it only builds typescript and passes normally every time (with the new and old code)

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62184145/aws-elastic-beanstalk-wont-deploy-my-rails-app-even-once) issue? Seems same as yours?

Comment: I did. It solved the issue, but then it reappeared again in couple of days. So it's not a permanent solution.
Also here it says that it happens when you try to terminate or rebuild the environment, but I didn't do it.

Comment: Glad to here. The only advice I can have is to keep monitoring the situation. Maybe some bug in EB?

Comment: Might be, I'm not sure. I'll keep writing updates here if I find something or the problem reappears.